# Using angular's $http service to call a js file?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, angularjs, node.js

I'm using angular with node and trying to connect to a mysql DB.

I'm using the node mysql module in this script (server.js):

```
var  mysql=require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection(
        {
            host         : 'localhost',
            user         : 'root',
            password : '',
            database : 'mysql',
        }
);

connection.connect();

var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM users';

connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    for (var i in rows) {
        console.log('Post Titles: ', rows[i].post_title);
    }
});

connection.end();
```

I want to run the js script with angular like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('AppListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('../scripts/server.js').success(function(data) {
            console.dir(data);
        });
    }
```

This does not work (the js file is not actually executed). Do I have to wrap my js up in html? Am I going about this the wrong way? I'd like to do this all with js instead of having to use php or another language here.

Comment: Are you actually running this through a node server or are you trying to execute the above script in a browser?

Comment: Sorry I might have been unclear about what I'm trying to do. The second snippet is actually the "controllers.js" file in my angular project. From that file I'm trying to make an ajax request with server.js. So I guess I'm trying to run a node.js script from my angular project.

Comment: You can't just run a script on node and expect it to serve data to an external source, in your case Angular. You need to serve the data using a HTTP request/response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$http.get` method performs an AJAX request, so it will get the js file as a string for your JavaScript to consume.

Probably what you're looking for is JSONP, which will execute as JavaScript any file you download.  Try using `$http.jsonp` instead.

[Angular docs on `$http.jsonp`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp)